# cakephp Image Links with class associated

Tags: php, cakephp, html-helper

Using Cakephp html helper, how can i do this in cake?

```
<a class="logo" href="index.php">
 <img src="img/logo.png">
</a>
```

i did this:

```
echo $this->Html->image("logo.png", array( 
    "alt" => "Logo", 
    "class" => "logo", 
    'url' => array( 
        'controller' => 'Home', 
        'action' => 'index'
    )
));
```

this will do this html code:

```
<a href="/Root/Home/index/">
<img class='logo' alt="ArtBid Logo" src="/artbid/img/logo.png">
</a>
```

but the class 'logo' goes to img and not to the anchor which were supposed.

Answer (score 3):

You should use  `$this->Html->link()` around the image and set the class in there.

```
echo $this->Html->link(
    $this->Html->image("logo.png", array( 
        "alt" => "Logo"
    )),  
    array("controller" => "Home", "action" => "index"),
    array("class" => "logo", "escape" => false) 
);
```

Comment: I tried your code but it is not working, do you mean it:echo $this->Html->link($this->Html->image("logo.png", array( "alt" => "Logo")),array("class" => "logo","url" => array( "controller" => "Home", "action" => "index")));

Comment: something is not working:<a href="/root/dir1/<img src="/root/img/logo.png" alt="" />">/root/dir1/<img src="/root/img/logo.png" alt="" /></a>

Comment: Try to add `array('escape' => false)` after the array with the class

Answer (score 2):

```
echo $this->Html->link($this->Html->image('image.jpg', ['class' => 'imgClass']), ['controller' => 'contents', 'action' => 'home'], ['escape' => false, 'class' => 'linkClass']);
```